# Symfony mailer configuration error - shopware 6

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, shopware6

Symfony is throwing error when I try to send email. Apparently there is ssl certificate verification failure. The project is running on linux nginx server.

The `.env` file has following configuration.

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://user:pass@mail.ourserver.de??encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login
```

**Error log**

> app.ERROR: Could not send mail: Failed sending mail to following
> recipients: {{ recipients }} with Error: Connection could not be
> established with host "ssl://mail.ourserver.de  :465":
> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
> Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
> Error Code:0

Do I need to get ssl certificate for the domain in this case "mail.ourserver.de" and add `cert` and `key` in linux openssl configuration?

A hack to make it work! I have found it in stackoverflow answers, but not sure if it's a good practice and does that make the ssl connection vulnerable to attack?
**verify_peer=false** parameter

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://user:pass@mail.ourserver.de??encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&verify_peer=false
```

If i disable verify_peer option, it does work, but Is ssl verification taking place when peer verification is set to false or it's being completely disabled?

Comment: "Do I need to get ssl certificate for the domain"- if you don't use an SSL certificate, why do you use `encryption=ssl`?

Comment: Is this a self-signed certitficate?

Comment: I haven't added any certificate, that's where i am confused. For using smtp mailing server, do i need to add the certificates for that server? Do they have to be issued by certificate authority? Also my main question here is setting verify_peer=false? does this parameter disable ssl and make it less secure.

Comment: the mail server doesn't have a domain for now @NicoHaase

Comment: Well, if your server is not using any SSL certificate, why do you use `encryption=ssl`?

Comment: To add some kind of encryption, I wasn't aware that even for mailing server I will need to add certificates. I have used thirdparty mailing server with tls encryption, i didn't have to add ssl/tls certificates there. @NicoHaase

Comment: If they did not add a certificate, it's probably using the self-signed autogenerated one. Which mail server software are you using by the way?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing to verify your server's certificate. There's a guide for checking and updating certificates [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). (it's for `PHPMailer` but the parts regarding certificates are still relevant)

Answer (score 0):

If you did not add a SSL certificate yourself, but use SSL, you probably have an autogenerated, self signed certificate in place.

Yes, you should assign a domain name to the server and get some valid, trusted SSL certificate for it. You can use the free LetsEncrypt service. The details depend on the mail server software.